# SSRS Matrix: How to merge repeating cells w.r.t a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

[image: 8]
As shown in the screenshot above, I am experiencing issues trying to merge the Sum Delta column (highlighted in Yellow) in a matrix report ( Product is the column group, and Group-1 and Group-2 are the row groups. I am getting the Sum-Delta value from my data-set itself, but it is repeating for every row of Group-2. Is there a way I can merge these per Group-1?

Current report looks like below with SumDelta being repeated for every value of Group-2, when I want it to be non-repeating.

[image: Current Report]

Below is the screen-grab of the report viewer.
[image]

Comment: Not really clear what the issue is with this question.  Could you add a mock-up of what your expected result is if the above image is what is currently happening?

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your reply. I have updated the current way it is showing up.

Comment: You may need to do some work with the row groups.  I don't know exactly how this is going to work out, but you may be able to modify the row group for `Group 1` and just add `SumDelta` as an additional value to group by in the group properties.

Comment: Could you post a screen grab of your report in design view?

Comment: Hi @SuperSimmer44, added the screen-grab ... Let me know of what you think.

Comment: Hi @Steve-o169, that would repeat group-1 for each occurrence of unique group-2 value.

Comment: @Abhinav, go to Row Group properties of Group2 , General, and under Group expressions, Group on change to  Group1. This may get your desired results.

Comment: @SuperSimmer44, this would even aggregate the other columns like (Current Value, Target, Delta) under the group-1. Let me know if I am missing something here ?